# How to reliably identify a website

Tags: php, file, statistics

I have a file that is being linked to from other sub websites.

The file: `http://site.com/file.img`

Website A linking to it `<img src="http://site.com/file.img"></img>`

website B linking to it `<img src="http://site.com/file.img"></img>`

I need to reliably identify which of these websites has accessed the file, but I know that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be spoofed. What other ways do I have to reliably confirm the requester site? By IP, get them to register an IP? not sure. setup an API key? What options are there?

Comment: Getting the server's IP does not work because the image is served to the client.

Comment: We need more information here - what context are these images being used in? Is the remote site always authorized to show them? The answer is going to range from "private key signing" to "not possible" depending on the context.

Comment: @Chris, Please add yours as an answer so we can discuss there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a website is only *linking* to a file, the "website" itself will never actually access your image. Instead, the *client* who's viewing the site will make a request for the image.

As such, you're depending on information sent by the client, which is completely out of your control and not reliable at all. If you have the opportunity to set some sort of unique cookie on the client, you may be able to use this in some fashion for extended identification, but even that won't be reliable.

There is no 100% reliable solution.

Comment: +1. The problem with this scheme is its reliance on the presence of the optional HTTP referrer field. If your client doesn't supply this information, there's not much you can do other than play stupid client games (ie, http://yro.slashdot.org/story/10/05/19/1425240/76-Web-Users-Affected-By-Browser-History-Stealing).

Comment: @MrGomez, Wow I wonder how many developers and site owners play these stupid games. Not something that should be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the referrer is the best you can do without getting into complicated territory.

If you don't mind complicated, then read on: set up your Web server to serve `file.img` *only* to Website A and Website B, then require that Website A and Website B set up a proxy configuration on their end that will retrieve `file.img` on behalf of their visitors.

Example:

A visitor to Website A loads a page that contains an image tag like `<img src="http://websiteA.com/file.img"/>` (note reference to Website A rather than your site).  Client requests `file.img` from WebsiteA.com accordingly.  Website A is configured to proxy requests for the path `/file.img` to your server, `http://site.com/file.img`.  Your site verifies that it is in fact Website A that is requesting the image and then serves it to Website A's proxy.  Website A then serves it to the visitor.

Basically, that makes it a pain for Websites A and B, gives you a performance hit, and also requires further configuration on your part.  But I imagine that would satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how OpenID relying is implemented, it allows one site to authenticate against another.  The protocol specification will give a hint at the effort and overhead required to reliably implement such a scheme.

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/googles-sample-openid-relying-party.html